# Pandas resample / grouper and unique rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of the format:

```
                 bank_number  pixel_id
00:00:00                   1    773872
00:00:00.000001            1    754607
00:00:00.000002            2    758142
00:00:00.000003            2    780649
00:00:00.000004            1    734804
```

I would like to count the number of unique entries (`bank_number` and `pixel_id`) given a frequency for the index.

I can resample / group the index by frequency using either `df.resample("100us")` or `df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='100us'))`.
E.g:

```
In [10]: df.resample("100us").sum()
Out[10]: 
                 bank_number      pixel_id
00:00:00              100000   75387050532
00:00:00.000100       100000   75375499992
00:00:00.000200       100000   75383627514
00:00:00.000300       100000   75385717582
```

And I can get unique entries using `df.groupby(["bank_number", "pixel_id"]).size()`:

```
bank_number  pixel_id
0            1311297     1
             1311303     1
             1311304     5
```

But not the two together...
Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a 3rd column bank_pixel_id by concatenating bank_number and pixel_id

and then do

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='100us'))['bank_pixel_id'].agg('count')
```